# Upload list item attachment using JSOM

Tags: client-object-model, office-365, list-item, attachments

I am trying to upload list item attachment using the below code. There is no error in the code and all the variables are present with proper values but in `uploadFile` method it goes to error handler and says `File not found`. Can anyone help?

```
function UploadAttachment() {
 this.filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
 var args = window.frameElement.dialogArgs;
 this.itemId = args.ItemId; //$.QueryString["ItemId"];
 this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var outReachList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Outreach List');
 this.listItem = outReachList.getItemById(itemId);
 clientContext.load(listItem);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.HasListItemAttachment), Function.createDelegate(this, this.GetAllAttachmentsFailed));
}

function HasListItemAttachment() {
 var attachmentFolderUrl = String.format('{0}/Attachments/{1}',listItem.get_fieldValues()['FileDirRef'], itemId);
 console.log(attachmentFolderUrl);
 this.attachmentFolder = clientContext.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(attachmentFolderUrl);
 clientContext.load(attachmentFolder);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.uploadFile), Function.createDelegate(this, GetAllAttachmentsFailed));
}

//function to actually upload file
function uploadFile() {
 var file = document.getElementById("customFileUploadControl").files[0];
 getFileBuffer(file).then( function(buffer) {
 var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
 var content = new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray(); //base64 encoding
 for (var b = 0; b < bytes.length; b++) {
     content.append(bytes[b]);
  }
  var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
  createInfo.set_content(content); //setting the content of the new file
  createInfo.set_url(filename);
  attachmentFolder.add(createInfo);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, uploadFileSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, GetAllAttachmentsFailed));
 });
}

function uploadFileSuccess() {
SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
 }

function GetAllAttachmentsFailed(sender, args) {
console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }

 function getFileBuffer(file){
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e){
    deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
}
reader.onerror = function(e){
    deferred.reject(e.target.error);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
return deferred.promise();
 }
```

Comment: did you tried SPServices http://sympmarc.com/2014/05/27/uploading-attachments-to-sharepoint-lists-using-spservices/?

Comment: no I didn't. I am interested to know why this is not working before moving on to other approaches.

Comment: are you using Ajax/Update panel in page?

Comment: no. just normal html file upload control and a submit button. on click calling this method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably the error `File not found` occurs since you are trying to retrieve attachments folder *that not yet exist* in method `HasListItemAttachment`

The following example demonstrates how to upload attachment file via SharePoint JSOM:

```
function processUpload(fileInput, listTitle, itemId,success,error) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (result) {
        var fileContent = new Uint8Array(result.target.result);
        performAttachmentUpload(listTitle, fileInput.name, itemId, fileContent,success,error);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput);
}


function performAttachmentUpload(listTitle, fileName, itemId, fileContent,success,error) {

    ensureAttachmentFolder(listTitle,itemId, 
       function(folder){
           var attachmentFolderUrl = folder.get_serverRelativeUrl();
           uploadFile(attachmentFolderUrl,fileName,fileContent,success,error);
       },
       error);
}


function ensureAttachmentFolder(listTitle,itemId, success,error)
{
      var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var web = ctx.get_web();
      var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
      ctx.load(list,'RootFolder');
      var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
      ctx.load(item);
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            var attachmentsFolder;
            if(!item.get_fieldValues()['Attachments']) { /* Attachments folder exists? */
               var attachmentRootFolderUrl = String.format('{0}/Attachments',list.get_rootFolder().get_serverRelativeUrl()); 
               var attachmentsRootFolder = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(attachmentRootFolderUrl);
               //Note: Here is a tricky part. 
               //Since SharePoint prevents the creation of folder with name that corresponds to item id, we are going to:   
               //1)create a folder with name in the following format '_<itemid>'
               //2)rename a folder from '_<itemid>'' into '<itemid>'
               //This allow to bypass the limitation of creating attachment folders
               attachmentsFolder = attachmentsRootFolder.get_folders().add('_' + itemId);
               attachmentsFolder.moveTo(attachmentRootFolderUrl + '/' + itemId);
               ctx.load(attachmentsFolder);
            }
            else {
               var attachmentFolderUrl = String.format('{0}/Attachments/{1}',list.get_rootFolder().get_serverRelativeUrl(),itemId); 
               attachmentsFolder = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(attachmentFolderUrl);
               ctx.load(attachmentsFolder);
            }         
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                 function() {
                     success(attachmentsFolder); 
                 },
                 error);
        },
        error);
}


function uploadFile(folderUrl,fileName,fileContent,success,error)
{
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var folder = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
     var encContent = new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray(); 
     for (var b = 0; b < fileContent.length; b++) {
         encContent.append(fileContent[b]);
     }
     var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
     createInfo.set_content(encContent); 
     createInfo.set_url(fileName);
     folder.get_files().add(createInfo);
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
}
```

> Note: It has been tested in SharePoint 2013/SPO

**Usage**

```
var listTitle = 'Contacts';
var itemId = 1;
var fileInput = document.getElementById("customFileUploadControl");
var file = fileInput.files[0];
processUpload(file,  listTitle, itemId,
  function(){
     console.log('Attachment file has been uploaded');  
  }, 
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

Comment: attachmentsFolder.moveTo() does not seem to work for me, function does not exist

Comment: Thank you very much for this code. It works fine, but it is missing some important part: when I remove the last file from an item, it seems that the field is unset but the folder still exists, what causes the routine to crash because of `moveTo` trying to override a file. Would you mind give me a hint how to solve this? I tried checking for existence but my code isn't working due to a lack of understanding the SP api, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late to the party, but when I tried the code above I too got the same error as "Elsni" (See below error message). I am not sure why there is a comment in the code saying you can not create attachment folders in order to get the code sample above to work I simply did this (see code below). Is this a SPO thing? I am using SP2013 on-prem, and I am running my test code as Site Admin, is this a permissions isssue?

```
//Note: Here is a tricky part. 
//Since SharePoint prevents the creation of folder with name that corresponds to item id, we are going to:   
//1)create a folder with name in the following format '_<itemid>'
//2)rename a folder from '_<itemid>'' into '<itemid>'
//This allow to bypass the limitation of creating attachment folders
//^^WHY?

attachmentsFolder = attachmentsRootFolder.get_folders().add(itemId);//.add('_' + itemId);
//attachmentsFolder.moveTo(attachmentRootFolderUrl + '/' + itemId);
ctx.load(attachmentsFolder);
```

Code seemed to run fine once I ditched the .moveTo method and just passed the itemID to the add method and as per the code above, I didn't use the underscore. I went to the form afterwards and the attachments showed up, as well as if I browser to i.e. http://server/site/web/list/attachments/1/ it shows a web page instead of an error so it worked just fine without the .moveTo

Thanks.
SG.

Error with the moveTo() method and original code:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'moveTo'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Vadim Gremyachev is nice and useful, but i would not check if the item had attachments, since admins could remove them from the db (using webdav) and the flag would be still on true. I would try to load the attachments folder, if it fails creted it, otherwise save atttachment:

```
var createFolder = function(itemId, folderUrl, callback){
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var attachmentsRootFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
    var attachmentsFolder = attachmentsRootFolder.get_folders().add('_'+itemId);
    attachmentsFolder.moveTo(folderUrl + itemId);
    ctx.load(attachmentsFolder);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        callback();

    }, function(request, response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}

var saveAttachment = function(itemId, filename, folderUrl, fileData){

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var attachmentFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl + itemId);
    var byteArray = new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray()

    for (var i = 0; i < fileData.length; ++i){
        byteArray.append(fileData[i]);
    }

    var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
    createInfo.set_content(byteArray); 
    createInfo.set_url(filename);
    attachmentFolder.get_files().add(createInfo);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){

        //do what you want

    }, function(request, response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}

var filename = yourFileName;
var itemId = theRelatedItemId;
var attachmentsFolderUrl = 'Lists/MyList/Attachments/';

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var attachmentFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(attachmentsFolderUrl + itemId);
ctx.load(attachmentFolder);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){

    saveAttachment(itemId, filename, attachmentsFolderUrl, array);

}, function(a,b){

    createFolder(itemId, attachmentsFolderUrl, function(){
        saveAttachment(itemId, filename, attachmentsFolderUrl, array);
    });
});
```