# Upload Attachments on SP CUSTOM list

Tags: list, javascript, jsom, attachments

I'm using HTML to create a custom list with bootstrap and then JSOM to manipulate and display the list on a SP custom list.

I am looking to add attachments and I can't figure it out.

Can anyone help?

The HTML code is self explanatory so I won't include it.

Here is my JS Code:

```
<script>
var siteUrl = 'url goes HERE';  //use site URL where list is being hosted (NOT LIST URL)
function InsertintGetList() {  
    var spendPlanType = document.getElementById('spendPlanType').value;  
    var monthS = document.getElementById('month').value;  
    var dSS = document.getElementById('dSS').value;  
    var directorate = document.getElementById('directorate').value;  
    var description = document.getElementById('description').value;  
    var projectedA = document.getElementById('projectedA').value;  
    var actualA = document.getElementById('actualA').value;  
    var justification = document.getElementById('justification').value;  
    var startD = document.getElementById('startD').value;
    var endD = document.getElementById('endD').value;
    var recompete = document.getElementById('recompete').value;
    var documentNumber = document.getElementById('documentNumber').value;
    var contractNumber = document.getElementById('contractNumber').value;
    var pec = document.getElementById('pec').value;
    var rccc = document.getElementById('rccc').value; 
    var subObjectClass = document.getElementById('subObjectClass').value; 
    var eEIC = document.getElementById('eEIC').value; 
    var espCode = document.getElementById('espCode').value;
    var recuring = document.getElementById('recuring').value;
    var techPm = document.getElementById('techPm').value; 
    var dateObligated = document.getElementById('dateObligated').value; 
    var notes = document.getElementById('notes').value; 
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);  
    var GetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('SpendPlan');  //name of list on SharePoint
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
        this.GetListItem = GetList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);  
        GetListItem.set_item('Spend_x0020_Plan', spendPlanType); 
        GetListItem.set_item('Month', monthS);  
        GetListItem.set_item('d_x002f_SS', dSS);  
        GetListItem.set_item('Directorates', directorate);  
        GetListItem.set_item('Description', description);
        GetListItem.set_item('Projected_x0020_Amount', projectedA);  
        GetListItem.set_item('Actual_x0020_Amount', actualA);  
        GetListItem.set_item('Justification_x002f_Mission', justification);  
        GetListItem.set_item('PoP_x0020_Start_x0020_Date', startD);  
        GetListItem.set_item('PoP_x0020_End_x0020_Date', endD);
        GetListItem.set_item('Recompete_x0020_Date', recompete);
        GetListItem.set_item('Document_x0020_Number', documentNumber);
        GetListItem.set_item('Contract_x0020_Number', contractNumber);
        GetListItem.set_item('PEC', pec );
        GetListItem.set_item('RCCC', rccc);
        GetListItem.set_item('Sub_x0020_object_x0020_Class', subObjectClass);
        GetListItem.set_item('EEIC', eEIC);
        GetListItem.set_item('ESP_x0020_Code', espCode);
        GetListItem.set_item('One_x002d_time_x0020_or_x0020_Re', recuring);
        GetListItem.set_item('Tech_x002f_PM_x0020_POC', techPm);
        GetListItem.set_item('Date_x0020_Obligated', dateObligated);
        GetListItem.set_item('Notes', notes);
        GetListItem.update();  
        clientContext.load(GetListItem);  
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));  
    }  
function onQuerySucceeded() {  
    alert('Record Inserted'); 
    document.getElementById("spendPlanType").value = "";   
    document.getElementById("month").value = "";  
    document.getElementById("dSS").value = "";  
    document.getElementById("directorate").value = "";  
    document.getElementById("description").value = "";  
    document.getElementById("projectedA").value = "";  
    document.getElementById("actualA").value = "";  
    document.getElementById("justification").value = "";  
    document.getElementById('startD').value = "";
    document.getElementById('endD').value = "";
    document.getElementById("recompete").value = "";  
    document.getElementById("documentNumber").value = "";  
    document.getElementById('contractNumber').value = "";
    document.getElementById('pec').value = "";
    document.getElementById("rccc").value = "";  
    document.getElementById("subObjectClass").value = "";  
    document.getElementById('eEIC').value = "";
    document.getElementById('espCode').value = "";
    document.getElementById("recuring").value = "";   
    document.getElementById("techPm").value = "";  
    document.getElementById("dateObligated").value = "";  
    document.getElementById("notes").value = ""; 
}  
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {  
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
   }  
   
</script>
```

Comment: You can take reference from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-file-to-listitem-in-office-365-as-an-attachment-using-javascript-object-m/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upload attachments to SharePoint list item using JSOM.

Here's the sample code taken from 1st reference link (given below):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fileInput;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        fileInput = $("#getFile");
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', registerClick);
    });

    function registerClick() {
        //Register File Upload Click Event  
        $("#addFileButton").click(readFile);
    }
    var arrayBuffer;

    function readFile() {
        //Get File Input Control and read th file name  
        var element = document.getElementById("getFile");
        var file = element.files[0];
        var parts = element.value.split("\\");
        var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
        //Read File contents using file reader  
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            uploadFile(e.target.result, fileName);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            alert(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
    var attachmentFiles, clientContext, createInfo;

    function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, fileName) {
        //Get Client Context and Web object.  
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();

        //Get list and Attachment folder where the attachment of a particular list item is stored.  
        var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('NewList');
        var attachmentFolder = oWeb.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/dev/Lists/NewList/Attachments/1');

        //Convert the file contents into base64 data  
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        var i, length, out = '';
        for (i = 0, length = bytes.length; i < length; i += 1) {
            out += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }
        var base64 = btoa(out);
        //Create FileCreationInformation object using the read file data  
        createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
        createInfo.set_content(base64);
        createInfo.set_url(fileName);

        //Add the file to the list item  
        attachmentFiles = attachmentFolder.get_files().add(createInfo);

        //Load client context and execute the batch  
        clientContext.load(oList);
        clientContext.load(attachmentFiles);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);
    }

    function QuerySuccess() {
        console.log("Attachment added successfuly ");
    }

    function QueryFailure(sender, args) {
        console.log('Request failed with error message - ' + args.get_message() + ' . Stack Trace - ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }  
</script>

<input id="getFile" type="file" /><br />
<input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="Upload" />
```

Where `NewList` is name of the list (name in URL & not display name) and `1` is list item ID at this line:

```
var attachmentFolder = oWeb.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/dev/Lists/NewList/Attachments/1');
```

Refer below articles for detailed information & code snippets:

1. [Upload list item attachment using JSOM](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/356d4a5b-2c22-497c-97ca-0bc24d8d9231/upload-list-item-attachment-using-jsom)
2. [Upload list item attachment using JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136577/upload-list-item-attachment-using-jsom)
3. [Upload File To List Item In Office 365 As An Attachment Using JavaScript Object Model](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-file-to-listitem-in-office-365-as-an-attachment-using-javascript-object-m/)

Comment: The code I have above creates a new item in a list using JSOM. Do I have to add the id manually so that the attachment can be uploaded to the correct item? Or will it be done automatically with each new list I create?

Comment: You can get the item ID of newly created list item in `onQuerySucceeded` function. Inside this function, you can call the function to upload the attachments.